# Dedication page for master thesis

Tags: thesis

I am beginner in LaTeX and I want make a dedication page like this.

[image: dedication page]

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}

\begin{document}

\title{Sécurité des véhicules  connectés:authentification dans CAN}
\date{2 Octobre 2016}
\author{Samir}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\newpage

{\bf\huge DEDICACES}

A DIEU TOUT PUISSANT}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide the community with some foundation to work from? Something you have tried? Perhaps in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: That should not be too hard, but it can greatly help others to know what document class you use and how the rest of your documents looks and is structured. So you might want to show us an MWE.

Answer (score 1):

[image: samirfassakDedicationPage]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}

\begin{document}

\title{Sécurité des véhicules  connectés: authentification dans CAN}
\date{2 Octobre 2016}
\author{Samir}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\begingroup
\centering
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
{\bfseries\huge DEDICACES}

A DIEU TOUT PUISSANT

some more text

a Wombat, a Capybara and a Duck

\endgroup
\end{document}
```